# Suitable Device management for use with Azure resource

Tags: c#, azure, iot, azure-table-storage, azure-iot-hub

I am developing an Web App. Its main functionality is

- to provide options to get data from different devices and
- display them on Dashboard

**My Current Flow**
When it was started

- A device will be sending data
- This data from the device will to be placed in Azure Table Storage.
- As and when the data gets into Azure the latest received data will be flashing (displayed) in my web app Dashboard.

**The app is now getting bigger**

- we are expecting to get data from more than one device
- each device may have same\different parameters & values to send to the Azure
- So management of the parameters corresponding to each device too needs to be handled

For all this, its required to make the app manage the devices- like

- registering new device,
- allow edit\delete of the devices
- maintaining the device related  parameters
- ...
- ...

**My Query**

1. In this scenario would the device with IoT Hub serve my cause?
2. Or Should I make my web app only to manage (add\edit\del..) devices
3. Or is there any better option in Azure to manage device that send data to be placed on the Azure resource?

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. In this scenario would the device with IoT Hub serve my cause?

Device management with IoT Hub can serve you cause. Please refer to [Overview of device management with IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-device-management-overview), in this article there is introduction about Azure IoT Hub.

> 2. Or Should I make my web app only to manage (add\edit\del..) devices
> 3. Or is there any better option in Azure to manage device that send data to be placed on the Azure resource?

The repository of [Microsoft Azure IoT SDK for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp) contains IoT service SDKs, you can use this SDK in you web app to manage the devices.The basic features of the tool **DeviceExplorer**  in this repository are similar with your requirements, such as device management, receiving message from devices, sending data to devices by call method on devices. Even though, this tool is a desktop application, you can try to transplant the features in web app.